# Destruct column into multiple columns with Regex on Azure?

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql

I've encountered a problem which I think can only be solved by regex functions only.
Sadly the support for regex based operations seems to be very poor on Microsoft side.
(Forgive me if I'm wrong, that's the first case when I've to use this platform)

**What I've:**

- ~400 million records in MS Azure SQL DB
- encoded functionality what I've to decode into multiple columns (later I'll join metadata by these columns)

**What I need:**

- a regex based function which can parse out the data (the output will be written into `de1-6` columns)

The encoded column (what needs to be decoded) looks like this:

```
|encoded_val  |
|-------------|
|PIT273OF_21  |
|PT273CT_21   |
|LT171CT2_31  |
|TV273JM_11   |
|TV273CND_13  |
|FIT865_11_CLC|
|AT865_104    |
|E865MFSP01   |
|LIT273CU_61  |
|E273_RH      |
|E273CU_GTH   |
|VSZ171JM_31  |
|E171CU_GTH   |
|IT171RC_11   |
|WY171CU_61N  |
|FV864_11     |
```

I need to decode this column with a regexp and create multiple columns with

```
| encoded       | de1 | de2 | de3  | de4  | de5  | de6  |
|---------------|-----|-----|------|------|------|------|
| PIT273OF_21   | PIT | 273 | OF   | NULL | 21   | NULL |
| PT273CT_21    | PT  | 273 | CT   | NULL | 21   | NULL |
| LT171CT2_31   | LT  | 171 | CT   | 2    | 31   | NULL |
| TV273JM_11    | TV  | 273 | JM   | NULL | 11   | NULL |
| TV273CND_13   | TV  | 273 | CND  | NULL | 13   | NULL |
| FIT865_11_CLC | FIT | 865 | NULL | NULL | 11   | CLC  |
| AT865_104     | AT  | 865 | NULL | NULL | 104  | NULL |
| E865MFSP01    | E   | 865 | MFSP | 01   | NULL | NULL |
| LIT273CU_61   | LIT | 273 | CU   | NULL | 61   | NULL |
| E273_RH       | E   | 273 | NULL | NULL | NULL | RH   |
| E273CU_GTH    | E   | 273 | CU   | NULL | NULL | GTH  |
| VSZ171JM_31   | VSZ | 171 | JM   | NULL | 31   | NULL |
| E171CU_GTH    | E   | 171 | CU   | NULL | NULL | GTH  |
| IT171RC_11    | IT  | 171 | RC   | NULL | 11   | NULL |
| WY171CU_61N   | WY  | 171 | CU   | NULL | 61   | N    |
| FV864_11      | FV  | 864 | NULL | NULL | 11   | NULL |
```

**Problems**

- the format is not fixed
- the length of the blocks can vary
- there can be missing values

... but let's say, I've some magic regex pattern, what can parse useful data from any string

**What I've tried:**

- compute columns - they seem to only construct new columns from existing ones, not to destruct existing columns into new columns in clever way with pattern matching
- user defined function - I did not figured out yet, how they could help, but they seem promising
- overcomplicated functions what are impossible to understand/maintain, their execution time seems to be unacceptable

```
update [bd].[table]
set unitid = cast(LEFT(SUBSTRING([colname],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[colname]),100),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING([colname],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[colname]),100) + '*') -1) as smallint);
```

**Question:**

What is the appropriate way to do this fast (on 400M records)?

Comment: SQL Server, and other RDBMS, have rows and columns, not "records".

Comment: thanks for the correction! As I've written, I've came from a different world... but does this solve the problem?

Comment: Common terminology makes it easier to understand each other.

Comment: Okay, I agree, but may I ask which part of the question is unclear due to using "records" instead of "rows"?

Comment: The problem is people use "records" interchangeably. Some people mean rows, some columns, some even a single row and column entity (so a column with 100 rows and 10 columns has 1,000 "records").

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [encoded] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into [Sample] values ('FIT865_11_CLC')
insert into [Sample] values ('PIT273OF_21')



declare @count int
declare @id int
declare @content varchar(50)
declare @table table
(
    id int,
    String varchar(256)
)

set @count = (select count(1) from sample)
set @id = 0

while(@count > 0)
begin

    if (@id > 0)
        select top(1) @id = id, @content = encoded from Sample where id > @id order by id
    else
        select top(1) @id = id, @content = encoded from Sample order by id


    declare @len int = len(@content)
    declare @position int = 1
    declare @output varchar(256) = ''

    declare @currentChar varchar(1)
    declare @lastChar varchar(1)


    while(@len > 0)
    begin
        set @currentChar = (select substring(@content, @position, 1))

        if(@position = 1)
        begin
            set @lastChar = @currentChar
        end


        if(ISNUMERIC(@currentChar)<> ISNUMERIC(@lastChar)) --alpha
            set @output = @output + ',' + @currentChar
        else
            set @output = @output + @currentChar


        set @len = @len -1
        set @position = @position + 1

        set @lastChar = @currentChar


    end

    set @count = @count - 1
    set @output = (select replace (@output,'_',','))

    insert into @table values (@id, @output)


end

SELECT DISTINCT B.* 
FROM @table A
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
             JSON_VALUE(J,'$[0]') AS de0
            ,JSON_VALUE(J,'$[1]') AS de1
            ,JSON_VALUE(J,'$[2]') AS de2
            ,JSON_VALUE(J,'$[3]') AS de3
            ,JSON_VALUE(J,'$[4]') AS de4
            ,JSON_VALUE(J,'$[5]') AS de5
            ,JSON_VALUE(J,'$[6]') AS de6
            ,JSON_VALUE(J,'$[7]') AS de7
      FROM (VALUES ('["'+replace(replace(String,'"','\"'),',','","')+'"]')) A(J)
) B
```